# How to pass in ansible-playbook command more advanced --extra-vars?

Tags: ansible

How to pass variables like this list in command with ansible-playbook?

````
users:
  - { name: Name, surname: Surname, login: example, email: example@example.com }```
````

Comment: See the documentation examples under [Defining variables at runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime).

Answer (score 2):

Put the extra variable(s) into a file. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat users.yml 
users:
  - {name: Alice, surname: Example, login: alice, email: alice@example.com}
  - {name: Bob, surname: Example, login: bob, email: bob@example.com}
```

Then, you can use it without any conversions. For example, the play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          name: {{ item.name }}
          email: {{ item.email }}
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

gives (limited to *host_1*)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -l host_1 -e @users.yml pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_1] => (item=Alice) => 
  msg: |-
    name: Alice
    email: alice@example.com
ok: [host_1] => (item=Bob) => 
  msg: |-
    name: Bob
    email: bob@example.com

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think passing in complex variables like that on the command line is probably a bad idea (there are many opportunities for typos); you're better off writing the information to a file and then setting a variable to the contents of the file (`-e users=@users.txt`).

But it is possible.

If you create a playbook like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "name: {{ item.name }}"
          - "email: {{ item.email }}"
      loop: "{{ users|from_yaml }}"
```

Then you could pass in your `users` variable like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml  -e users='"
- { name: Alice, surname: Example, login: alice, email: alice@example.com }
- { name: Bob, surname: Example, login: bob, email: bob@example.com }
"'
```

Running that command with the example playbook results in:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'Alice', 'surname': 'Example', 'login': 'alice', 'email': 'alice@example.com'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "name: Alice",
        "email: alice@example.com"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'Bob', 'surname': 'Example', 'login': 'bob', 'email': 'bob@example.com'}) => {
    "msg": [
        "name: Bob",
        "email: bob@example.com"
    ]
}
```